# Is there a pythonic way to group range based segmented functions into a single function?

Tags: python, function, lambda

I have an array of functions [f(x),g(x),...]
What I want to do is call the appropriate function based on the range that the value of x is in.

```
f = lambda x: x+1
g = lambda x: x-1
h = lambda x: x*x
funcs = [f,g,h]
def superFunction(x):
    if x <= 20:
      return(funcs[0](x))
    if 20 < x <= 40:
      return(funcs[1](x))
    if x > 40:
      return(funcs[2](x))
```

Is there a nicer/pythonic way to do this handling a dynamic number of functions

The plan is to dynamically generate n number of polyfit functions along sections of data, then combine them into a single callable function.

Comment: A heap/tree would seem obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use a dispatch sequence:

```
funcs = (
    (20, f),
    (40, g),
    (float('inf'), h),
)

def superFunction(x):
    for limit, f in funcs:
        if x <= limit:
            return f(x)
```

or if the list of functions and limits is large, use a `bisect` search to find the closest limit.

Answer (score 1):

Using NumPy to do super-fast selection, in case you have a lot of choices (otherwise, why not stick with "if" statements):

```
import numpy as np
funcs = np.array([(20,f), (40,g), (np.inf,h)])

def superFunction(x):
    idx = np.argmax(x <= funcs[:,0])
    return funcs[idx,1](x)
```

This works like your original code, but the function selection happens in C rather than a Python loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use generic functions. For example [PEAK-Rules](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PEAK-Rules) allows this. Your code would look like this:

```
import peak.rules as pr

def myfunc(x):
    return x * x

@pr.when(myfunc, "x <= 20")
def myfunc_f(x):
    return x + 1

@pr.when(myfunc, "20 < x <= 40")
def myfunc_g(x):
    return x - 1

>>> myfunc(10)
11
>>> myfunc(30)
29
>>> myfunc(50)
2500
```

One advantage of generic functions is that they don't need to be defined in one place. myfunc_g could have been defined in a separate file to myfunc.

There are some problems this works really well for, e.g. adding custom JSON encoding rules to an existing class. Think carefully before you go down this route, I have seen examples of code made unnecessarily complicated using generic functions. The example you gave above I would leave exactly how you've presented it - although I expect your actual code is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take advantage of the fact that lambdas can be used as dict keys.  Fundamentally, you're associating these conditions with a function, so I think it fits well.  You only have to modify one place to add new conditions, which is an improvement as well.

```
funcs = {
    lambda x: x <= 20: lambda x: x + 1,
    lambda x: 20 < x <= 40: lambda x: x - 1,
    lambda x: x > 40: lambda x: x * x,
}

def superFunction(x):
    for condition, fn in funcs.iteritems():
        if condition(x):
            return fn(x)
```